# Smart House com Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

Olá, poderia me ajudar no TCC? preciso desenvolver uma página mobile como esta na imagem abaixo, estou utilizando Ionic 3 (Angular, TypeScript, HTML, CSS, PHP), e phppgadmin.
a ideia é de uma página aonde eu possa navegar pelos ambientes(quarto, sala, cozinha) e achar todos os componentes(luzes,janelas, etc..) que estão ativados ou desativados;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estão vendo essas caixas coloridas? elas seriam os componentes, eu precisaria selecionar os componentes cadastrados no banco nesse ambiente e popular essa área com essas caixas com o nome do componente e o status(ativado ou desativado), como poderia fazer essa população? seria um select e um for?

nessa caixa retangular fina branca estaria o nome do ambiente, e do lado um botão "<" e do lado direito ">" para realizar a paginação dos ambientes cadastrados no banco de dados, como poderia realizar essa paginação?

um protótipo que eu fiz até o momento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fiz as caixas vermelhas com gridlayout em SCSS.

pfv, me ajudem, como poderia realizar essas duas funções (paginação dos ambientes e a "população" dos componentes)?

Comment: Olá! Sua pergunta é interessante, mas está muito abrangente. Tente fechar o escopo do seu problema, mesmo que vire várias perguntas no SO, mostrando seu código atual e descrevendo em detalhes o que não está conseguindo fazer.